# I'm converting a docx page created by Apache POI into docx4j. Adding the altChunk resets fonts on previously created page

Tags: apache-poi, ms-office, docx4j

I'm loading a simple page with a header and styling created by POI and saved it as test.docx:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setFontFamily("Arial Narrow");
run.setFontSize(22);
run.setText("Test");
run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewHighlight().setVal(STHighlightColor.DARK_RED);
```

When I load it with docx4j and insert an altChunk then saving the document seems to result in resetting the font size and font family to Calibri and size 11.  Which i assume is the default font.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordmlPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream("test.docx"));

String pageBreak = "<html><body><br style='page-break-after: always; clear:both;' /></body></html>"

wordmlPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addAltChunk(AltChunkType.Html, pageBreak.getBytes());

wordmlPackage.save(new File("I:/local/FinalTestResult.docx"));
```

So my questions is, is there something I'm missing on why it is doing it and how can I prevent the document from resetting the font when adding a AltChunk?

Using: docx4j version 3.2.0

Edit:
I identified the cause of the change and included the line that's causing the issue on the original post:

```
run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewHighlight().setVal(STHighlightColor.DARK_RED);
```

It looks like if i add this to a run, it's reseting the fonts.  Not sure why though.